# tinyscrollbar jquery plugin not working online

Tags: jquery, tinyscrollbar

tinyscrollbar jquery plugin works correctly in an offline project:

[image]

but when lunch it from online server does not work:

[image]

Note: I did not change anything in an online version of the project but tinyscrollbar jquery plugin does not work.

Comment: Did you set a height for the images?